# bash: error handling on find -exec

Tags: bash, shell, find

I was using this little script to find malformed images:

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%f\n" {} \; 2>errors.txt
```

It worked well enough, but now I need to modify it slightly.  Instead of dumping the stderr to errors.txt, I want to dump the filename (%f) of the image that triggered the error.  That is, I want a list of the malformed image files in errors.txt instead of a list error messages.

I tried adding || echo "%f" >> errors.txt to the -exec portion, but that didn't work.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This finds malformed images and stores their names in `names.txt`:

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'identify "$1" &>/dev/null || echo "$1">>names.txt' none {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find -name '*.jpg'`

  This starts up `find` as usual.
- `-exec bash -c 'identify "$1" &>/dev/null || echo "$1" >>names.txt' none {} \;`

  This runs `identify` on each file and, if `identify` returns a non-zero error code, it echoes the file name to `names.txt`.

  `bash -c '...' none {}` causes a bash shell to run the command in the quotes with the file name in `{}` assigned to positional argument `$1`.

  For the curious, the string `none` is assigned to `$0`.  `$0` is not used *unless* bash generates an error in which case [it will appear in the error message as the program name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867117/3030305).

#### Discussion

> I tried adding `|| echo "%f" >> errors.txt` to the -exec portion, but that didn't work. What would be the best way to do this?

The subtlety is that the `||` has to operate on the `identify` command.  To do that, we need to put `identify` in a shell such as by using `bash -c` as shown above.

Comment: Works great, and thanks for the explanation -- the 'bash' addition makes perfect sense.  One minor thing: I had to change >names.txt to >>names.txt in order to get a list.

Comment: @Phll Glad it worked for you.  Sorry about the `>` thing: the answer is now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    if identify "$file"; then
      printf "%s\n" "$file" >&3
    else
      printf "%s\n" "$file" >&4
    fi
  done' sh {} + 3> good 4> bad > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want like...

```
find . -name '*.jpg'  \
       ! -exec identify -silent {} \; \
       -print 2>/dev/null >errors.txt
```